# input value text field in jsp error

Tags: java, jsp

My index.jsp is as following:

```
<form action="FileUploadServlet" id="formSubmit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="txtFileName" value="${fname}"/>
    <input type="file" name="fileName" id="selectedFile" style="display: none;">
    <input type="button" id="btnBrowse" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="btnUpload">
</form>
```

with `value=${fname}` is get from dopost method in servlet when form summited

```
request.setAttribute("fname", fileName);
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
```

But it's weird that when I deployed `index.jsp`
My text field always show `${fname}` in text area, even after form submitted, its still get that value (correctly it must show 'filename')

Does anyone meet this problem like me?

Comment: Does value="<%= request.getAttribute("fname") %>" work? What server are you using?

Comment: Try RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(req,res);

Comment: Yes, value="<%= request.getAttribute("fname") %>" work for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that, you are using wrong syntax to display value in JSP.
Below syntax is wrong.

```
value="${fname}"
```

We use expression tag  fordisplaying value in JSP page. Expression tag convert into Java statement.

```
<%=request.getAttribute("fname")%>
```

When you first time open your index.jsp page, it will show you blank value and when request will come back from server side, then it will show you correct result.
Use below code.

```
    <%if(request.getAttribute("fname")!=null){%>
    <input type="text" value ="<%=request.getAttribute("fname") %>"/>
    <%}else
    { %>
    <input type="text"/>
    <%} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSP, the correct syntax to retrieve the values is

```
<%=request.getAttribute("fname")%>
```

This is known as assignment OR expression tag (`<%=%>`).

Try this ...

```
<form action="FileUploadServlet" id="formSubmit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="txtFileName" value="<%=request.getAttribute("fname")%>"/>
    <input type="file" name="fileName" id="selectedFile" style="display: none;">
    <input type="button" id="btnBrowse" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="btnUpload">
</form>
```

More related to this, [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-expression-tag).

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I didnt know about that.